# Passing variable to function with constant parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, const-correctness

I'm very confused. I saw that when the code be like

```
void fun(const char **p) { }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   fun(argv);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

And it shows `error: invalid conversion from 'char**' to 'const char**'`

But when the code be like

```
void test(const char *p) { }
int main()
{
    char *c = new char('a');
    test(c);
}
```

Then there is no compile error. What is the difference between two codes?
Why can the second code pass a variable to the function with constant parameter?

Comment: `void fun(const char *const *p)` works, and even `void fun(char *const *p)` works. To do such conversions with pointers to pointers, if you add `const` on the left, you also need to add it to all positions to the right of that. But I don't remember why the rules are like this.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion

Comment: @joergbrech Interesting FAQ, I knew the Derived** to Base** version of this issue. I hadn't realised that a similar problem applied to T** to const T**.

Comment: It's very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers to pointers are weird. Take this example

```cpp
const int i = 42;
int* p;
const int** pp = &p;  // safe?
*pp = &i;  // *pp refers to p, but has the type const int*
*p = 420;  // !!
```

Clearly you should not be able to defeat `const` just by assigning pointers around, so the conversion from `T**` to `const T**` is illegal.

---

But wait a minute, why is converting `T*` to `const T*` legal in the first place?

Right, it's because each `T` can be treated as a `const T`. A `const T` is only a restriction of `T`. No operation on `const T` will be illegal on `T`. If you view types as representing a set of legal operations on objects, then `const T` represents a subset of `T`.

However, restricting the *pointee* has the opposite effect on the *pointer*. A `const T*` is not a subset of `T*`. A `T*` can only point to non-const `T` while `const T*` can point to *any* `T`. In terms of just assignment on the pointer itself, `const T*` is a superset of `T*`<sup>†</sup>, not the other way around.

So why isn't a conversion from `T**` to `const T**` legal? Because `T*` is not a superset of `const T*`: not all `T*` can be treated as a `const T*`, as demonstrated by the opening snippet.

<sub>†But if you dereference the pointer, `const T` is a subset of `T` again, so `const T*` and `T*` aren't subsets of each other.</sub>